# Custom OutputCache provider is not working (get is called but not set or add)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, outputcache

In an ASP.NET MVC4 application I have a custom output cache provider defined.

My configuration is like this:

```
<system.web>
       <caching>
      <outputCache defaultProvider="DiskOutputCache" enableOutputCache="true"  >
        <providers>
          <add name="DiskOutputCache"  type="ProExam.DMC.MvcUtil.DiskOutputCache, ProExam.DMC.MvcUtil, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
        </providers>
      </outputCache>
      <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>
          <add name="forever" duration="2147483647" varyByParam="id" />
        </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
```

I have an action like this:

```
    [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "forever")]
    public ActionResult View(UrlParamString id)
    {
    ...
    }
```

When I run in debug, only the get method of my custom output cache provider is called.  Never the set or the add.  Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I have the exact same problem. But in my case it's when I introduce VaryByCustom. Only one varybycustom cache item calls the add/set. When the next custom value is returned, the add/set methods are not called!

Comment: We solved it. It was caused by a filter that always wrote a cookie for each and every request. Removing the cookie solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the duration. You defined an almost infinite cache duration this means while the app is running, it will not try to store your cache item again.

Duration is set in seconds... Try `duration="10"` or something and see what happens.

Apart from that you can also try to define `enabled="true" location="Server"` in your cache profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding location attribute to web.config entry.

```
<add name="LongLivedProfile" duration="86400" location="Any" varyByParam="*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you do not write any cookies during the request. Outputcache does not call add/set if you write a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Check This: [Custom OutputCache provider is not working (get is called but not set or add)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231105/custom-outputcache-provider-is-not-working-get-is-called-but-not-set-or-add/28971763#28971763)

It doesn't work if you are using cookies.

Also Check Note Section for CacheProfile: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hdxfb6cy(v=vs.100).aspx

This attribute is not supported for @ OutputCache directives included in user controls (.ascx files). When specified on a page, the value must match the names of one of the available entries in the outputCacheProfiles element under the outputCacheSettings section. If the name does not match a profile entry, an exception is thrown.